# Divergence in Performance: VNC Streaming a Windows VM - Autologon vs. RDP Session

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, streaming, vnc

In my Azure windows VM, I have configured a VNC server to facilitate streaming along with an Autologon user configured via the registry. This Autologon user enables seamless streaming through the VNC server. I have MSFS game in the VM.

However, I've observed two distinct performance scenarios:

**Scenario 1**: When I stream the VM via a VNC Client in the browser (with Autologon User session enabled), I'm experiencing a noticeable lag of approximately 700 ms. Additionally, the animations in MSFS are not rendering as smoothly as desired.

**Scenario 2**: Interestingly, if I initiate an RDP connection (with the same AutoLogon configured user), open MSFS from there, and subsequently close the RDP connection before streaming, I'm seeing a significant improvement in performance. The lag is reduced to approximately 200 ms, and the animations in MSFS become noticeably smoother.

I'm perplexed about the source of this performance differential. Could RDP be enabling some form of virtualization or visualization that enhances performance? Alternatively, might there be additional services running during RDP sessions that contribute to this improvement?

Furthermore, could this discrepancy be related to the Autologon User Session versus an RDP Created User Session, even when the user remains the same?

I've been grappling with this issue for quite some time and would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions you could provide.

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.